# Magento: Blocks on home page not shown after version upgrade?

Tags: magento

I updated my Magento from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.2 recently and 2 blocks are not shown after the update. This is the code in home CMS:

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/cat_list.phtml"}}  

{{block type="filterproducts/latest_home_list" template="callthis/filterproducts/list.phtml"}}
```

Any idea why they are not there after the update? The template files are there so that can not be the reason. I debugged the code and it seems its not going into the template files so I guess thats the reason, but why isnt it going there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the 1.9.2.2 version includes the SUPEE-6788 security patch, which fixes a vulnerability that allows access to private information. That means that the blocks used in CMS pages and emails must be whitelisted.
By default, only the `core/template` and `catalog/product_new` blocks types are allowed. To use other (in your case `catalog/navigation` and `filterproducts/latest_home_list`) you have to whitelist them.
To do that you simply need to include these in the `permission_block` table. You can do that by directly insert them in the db, or by using a setup script, which would look like:

```
<?php

/** @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()->insertMultiple(
    $installer->getTable('admin/permission_variable'),
    array(
        array('variable_name' => 'xml_path/custom/variable', 'is_allowed' => 1),
    )
);

$installer->getConnection()->insertMultiple(
    $installer->getTable('admin/permission_block'),
    array(
        array('block_name' => 'catalog/navigation', 'is_allowed' => 1),
        array('block_name' => 'filterproducts/latest_home_list', 'is_allowed' => 1)
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

note that the first part of this setup is to allow custom config variables, you don't need them for your current problem, I just include it for the sake of completeness.

You can find more information about what the patch do [in magento's website](http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details)

Comment: A usefull tool to find all non default blocks and variables: https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons#find-non-whitelisted-varsblocks-to-be-compatible-with-supee-6788-and-magento-1922

Comment: You can also set permissions via the Admin Panel -> System > Permissions > Blocks

Answer (score 2):

This is cause by one of the patch of your update.

Quick fix:

- Find the table `permission_block` in the database
- Add rows with `catalog/navigation` and `filterproducts/latest_home_list` to allow these blocks to show.
- Empty your cache

More documentation abour this update:

- http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788
- http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87214/how-to-check-which-modules-are-affected-by-security-patch-supee-6788/87262#87262